# block <a> inside inline <li> behaviour

Tags: html, css, block, inline

The following HTML / CSS result strikes me as odd and unexpected and I'm really looking for the logic behind the way this is parsed.

Suppose:

```css
#nav {
  list-style-type-none
}
#nav li {
  display: inline;
}
/* make the LI's stack horizontally */

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
/* display as block to add padding */
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This results in the `<li>`'s stacking vertically (like block elements) because of the `<a>`'s which are displayed as block elements. But I want the `<li>`'s to be stacked horizontally as I've defined them as inline elements.

The `<li>`'s are displayed as inline, why does the **inner** element `<a>` affect it?

Comment: I see `Home` and `About us` side by side.  They are not stacking vertically.

Comment: that's because of the type @Robbert.

Comment: You can fix it by changing `inline` to `inline-block`. But as far as the why `inline` isn't enough, I don't know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because inline elements wrapping around block level elements are split into block level by the child block. Here's a quote from the w3 spec:

> When an inline box contains an in-flow block-level box, the inline box (and its inline ancestors within the same line box) are broken around the block-level box (and any block-level siblings that are consecutive or separated only by collapsible whitespace and/or out-of-flow elements), splitting the inline box into two boxes (even if either side is empty), one on each side of the block-level box(es). The line boxes before the break and after the break are enclosed in anonymous block boxes, and the block-level box becomes a sibling of those anonymous boxes.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes

If you have a look at that link, you'll see their diagram of the "anonymous box" that wraps inline text within a block that is followed by a block-level element (in their case, a `<p>`). So to try to further explain, in that quote above, basically they're saying that the inline box parent is getting split into block level boxes by the child with the display: block on it.

Does that make sense?

In order to get this to work right, you could set the li to `display:inline-block`

For your convenience, I copied your code and made the change below.

```css
#nav {
  list-style-type-none
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* make the LI's stack horizontally */

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
/* display as block to add padding */
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's clear to me now that this is indeed what the creators of HTML intended. But the reason I chose for `display: inline;` was browser compatability. I just googled `display: inline-block` and found out it works even back until IE8. I'm less reluctant to use inline-block now