# Why <p> nested in <span> leads for a block element?

Tags: html, css

As `<span>` is an inline element and `<p>` is a block element I cannot understand how nesting a `<p>` element inside a `<span>` element will result with a block element. Here is my example:

```css
div {
  background-color: cyan;
  border: solid;
}

p {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span><p>STACK OVERFLOW</p> </span>
  <span><p>STACK OVERFLOW</p></span>
  <span><p>STACK OVERFLOW</p></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Types are not inherited, so when you nest a block element inside an inline one, they will remain as they were. So, your `span` is still inline, but `p` inside is not and thus it gives the impression you are getting.

Comment: @B001ᛦ: That question does not appear to address the CSS aspect of this one.

Comment: @BoltClock yea got it.. thx

Comment: a hint : add some style to the span and what is happening

Comment: This is probably the most suitable duplicate I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413095/block-a-inside-inline-li-behaviour (I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290281/what-goes-wrong-when-a-displayinline-custom-element-contains-displayblock-elem) as well but the "custom element" in the title is a red herring and is unrelated to the issue.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply cannot nest a `p` element inside a `span` element. The [span element's content model](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-span-element) should be [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-2), which excludes elements such as `p` and heading elements. Since the `span` element's end tag is not omissible (i.e. it is required), the `p` element's start tag does not implicitly close the `span` element, so you get a validation error. However, browsers try to recover from the error, and they still render the `p` element as a block element.

To avoid this type of error in the future, I recommend validating HTML code using the [W3C's HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and consulting the consulting the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) (or a similar reference) about content models.

Comment: While this is true, this does not address why the elements are laid out the way they are. Swap the span and p such that the p becomes the parent, apply display: inline to the p and display: block to the span, and the resulting layout is identical.

Comment: On closer inspection I think I see how it *does* address the question - "why does putting a p in a span result in a block?" "The browser renders the p through error recovery even though a p may not legally appear in the context of a span."